# Backbone Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

if I set attributes of this.toolBar before "new ToolBarView({model: this.toolBar})" ,it works well. But when I set after the it, I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call' " on Chrom.

this is my code:

```
var DoubleColorBallView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.toolBar = new ToolBarModel({
            leftBtn: 'garbageCan',
            rightBtn: 'nextPage'
        });
        this.toolBar.set({number: 1});   //works well

        var view = new ToolBarView({model: this.toolBar});

        this.toolBar.set({number: 2});    //get an error

        $("#toolBar").append(view.render().el);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the error? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Can you provide a demo of the problem? This fiddle has the necessary Backbone stuff already set up: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZByDK/

Comment: I have solved this problem. It caused by the ToolBarView event     "this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render());". When binding event handler that should be referenced, I EXCUTE the handler function. Remove the parentheses, then code works well. these two problem seems unrelated. However, the mistake indeed caused my problem. thank you for you help!

Comment: That makes sense. `this.render()` is a function call which will hand `render`'s return value to `listenTo` which will think it is a function; `this.render` is simply a reference to the function and that's what `listenTo` will be expecting in the third argument.

Comment: @user3409965 Consider adding your solution as an answer (it is OK to answer your own question) so that the question is properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. It caused by the ToolBarView event "this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render());". When binding event handler that should be referenced, I EXCUTE the handler function. Remove the parentheses, then code works well. these two problem seems unrelated. However, the mistake indeed caused my problem. thank you for your help!